# Haskell - how to cast types?

Tags: haskell, casting

I am trying to do following:

```
10 ** length xs * x
```

but I get:

> No instance for (Floating Int) arising
>   from a use of `**'

Comment: Oh, and just to be very clear: In general, you don't "cast" types in Haskell. There are various ways of converting between types, but no "type casts" in the usual sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `^` to raise to an integral power. There's no need to convert to float here.

Answer (score 6):

Besides [@sepp2k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889922/haskell-how-to-cast-types/2889926#2889926), if you somehow really need to convert from an integer to some other types of Num, use `fromIntegral`.

```
-- # fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b

10 ** fromIntegral (length xs) * x
```